# XcodeのUIButtonについての質問

Tags: swift, xcode, objective-c, xcode7

UIButtonをタップすると、下記画像の、上のチェックボタンのように、UIButtoに設定したimageが黒く変色しアクティブ状態になり、押されたことが視覚的にわかるようにしたいのですが

下記画像の、上のチェックボタンと全く同じアトリビュートの設定をしてもボタンを押した時アクティブにならないものがあります。

これは、なぜでしょうか？2枚目の画像が、上手くアクティブ状態になるボタンの設定値です

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/57643

Answer (score -1):

highlight Abject Image でできました